# Can someone explain this glideslope question?

Tags: aircraft-systems, glideslope

> 35. The glideslope deviation bar is covering the second upper dot. The required action to meet glideslope beam is to:

What does this question mean?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I changed your question to make the words clearer. But if I made a mistake, please edit it again yourself. The [tour] might help you to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 9):

If you are answering an FAA Knowledge Test question, the correct answer is to level off and intercept the glide slope.

While on the glide slope, pitch controls airspeed and power controls altitude, so you will need to add a bit of power. For small very small deviations caused by turbulence, just let the airspeed vary and use pitch for a short while. For larger deviations you won’t be able to capture the glide slope without adding power.

The amount of correction depends on how far away you are from the glide slope transmitter. Figure 139 from the Instrument Knowledge Test Supplement give you an idea of the amount of correction you need depending on how far away from the runway you are. So if you are near the outer marker, 2 dots would mean that you definitely need to add power, level off and intercept the glide slope. Near the runway 2 dots is less than 100' so a slight adjustment with pitch would be fine, presuming you were holding the glide slope until then.

[image: Instrument Knowledge Test Figure 139.png]

Answer (score 2):

You’re low.  Add power, tweak the nose up a bit.  Watch rated of descent decrease a couple hundred FPM. The glideslope bar will move down slowly. As it approaches center, reverse the correction by decreasing power and dropping the nose a little. Rate of descent will settle back down to your target. Add about half the power you just reduced to hold it there.  By this time it’ll be time for a new correction.

Answer (score 2):

It's referring to the dots for the glideslope on the Horizontal Situation Indicator. (Shown on the left side of the diagram below)

[image]

<sup>[source](http://learntoflyblog.com/2016/03/17/cfi-brief-horizontal-situation-indicator-hsi/)</sup>

The dots above center indicate the plane is below the glide slope so rate of descent needs to be reduced.